# detecting if a checkbox is ticked inside a target div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have the following markup, below the closing span tag is a number list items.

```
<div class="header_block">
   <span class="background_flag_container">
      <input id="block_background" type="checkbox" name="block_background">
      <span class="background_flag_text">Has Banner Background</span>
   </span>
   ...
</div>
```

This is my jQuery. What I am looking to do is check if the one and only checkbox, with a name of 'block_background' is checked. There are a number of 'block_background' checkboxes on the page, but there will only ever be *one* within `$(this)` which is the `.header_block` div.

```
$(this).find(".background_flag_container input:checkbox[name='block_background']").each(function(){
   if ($(this).checked) {
      console.log('is checked');
   }
});
```

How can I check if it's checked?

Comment: jQuery is awesome but you're doing it kind of wrong. As @wirey explained, use `this.checked` also your selector is wrong-ish, if that is indeed your html you can just use `$(this).find('input')`, I'm uncertain what `this` is in your code, probably could be optimized more.

Comment: @Khez No problem, I have no issue when someone points out when i'm doing something wrong (in the way you have done).

Comment: @crmpicco Somehow I feel you took it as an insult, didn't mean it that way. Just wanted to make that clear...

Comment: @Khez No, the opposite. I replied as you _hadn't_ just flew in there with a sarcastic comment...I upvoted your comment. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  `is(':checked')` to check if something is selected

```
   $(this).find(".background_flag_container input:checkbox[name='block_background']").each(function(){
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          console.log('is checked');
       }
    });
```

Although seeing that the checkbox has the id `block_background` which should be unique. You could just do this:

```
if ($('#block_background').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('is checked');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input#block_background]").is(':checked')
```